# Fails to compile

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, nasm, kali-linux

I try to run the following:

build.sh:

```
nasm -felf64 hello.asm && gcc hello.o && ./a.out
```

but for some reason it fails, and produces the following error, which I'm not quite sure why. I would like to know if there is any way to solve this problem.

error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

hello.asm

```
      global    main
      extern    puts
      section   .text
main:                                       ; This is called by the C library startup code
          mov       rdi, message            ; First integer (or pointer) argument in rdi
          call      puts                    ; puts(message)
          ret                               ; Return from main back into C library wrapper
message:
          db        "Hello, World", 0
```

Comment: Did you try recompiling with `-fPIE`?

Comment: @mkayaalp: That's only relevant for C or C++ source, not assembly.  What you need here is actually `-no-pie`.  I'm sure we have a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, I had to use -no-pie.